# What do you put for handler and user data in the gtkbutton (glade)?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

I want the button to open the terminal and run a command when I click on it, with python(glade)

[image: I want the button to open the terminal and run a command when I click on it, with python(glade)]

Comment: If its python... why you have tagged JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

Handler is the name of your callback function in your code.

`user_data` is where you put some data to reuse in the callback. I think there are data models avalable for that in glade, but I don't know how you can use that with more complex structures...